# Tips for Securing a LAMP Server

Tags: security, lamp

what are the absolute security guidelines for  a server with LAMP stack?

Comment: You might want to try http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Also, you must make sure that you have changed Apache's administrative interface default password. It's the easiest way to hack a LAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) if you are using ssh to auto-ban IPs that try to hack your server using basic scripting techniques.

Also be sure your site folders (i.e. /var/www/) are owned by the server "user" this is somtimes "www-data" or "nobody" and I think even occasionally "apache", depending on your distro etc. From then on, be careful about the permissions, I'm sure you can google for permissions for web folders.

Update early and often (make backups before you do).